# Repair a pinhole leak in tankless water heater

Tags: plumbing, tankless, solder

Its been a hard winter on plumbing, and I had some freezing pipes when I lost power for a few days and it was in the teens.  The water was shut off but didn't drain the pipes.  I had a pipe burst and a pex manifold burst too, and after getting all those hooked up there was a drip coming from the tankless water heater.  I was able to get a picture of it, and wondering about fixing it.  I was thinking I'd try cleaning it up, flux it and reflow some solder.  I'm looking for advice on that or any other approaches or products.[image: tankless hole closeup]

[image: tankless water heater]

Comment: To solder it, it needs that section to be drained of water.  Unless there is a hidden drain, it looks like it will need to be removed from the wall to remove water from the bottom.

Comment: @crip659 no need to remove from wall ... insert a flexible tube and suck out the water

Comment: @jsotola   Never did that with water.  Gas, diesel, and wine, yes.  Wine(homemade) tasted a lot better than the other two.

Comment: @crip659 Thanks, no problem to remove it.  Its just hanging on screws and the pipes are compression fittings.  I suppose you'd suggest removing the whole copper part from the electronics and plastic mounting plate as well?  thanks

Comment: @freshop  It depends on how close the the plastic/electronics are to the heat/torch and how careful/not worry you want to be.  There seems to be an air space between them, so removing will be more up to you.